# Showing raster tiles in Mapbox GL JS from ArcGIS Server (tiles created in a different spatial reference system)

Tags: raster, coordinate-system, tiles, mapbox

I have a web app showing a Mapbox GL JS map, I want to add a raster source to show tiles from a public ArcGIS server (Tel-Aviv city's GIS web-app), issue is they use a different SRS ([epsg:2039](https://epsg.io/2039)) and Mapbox doesn't support it.

This is the GIS web app of Tel-Aviv:
https://gisn.tel-aviv.gov.il/arcgis/rest/services/IView2Ortho2021/MapServer?f=jsapi

Here's the ArcGIS's MapServer description page:
https://gisn.tel-aviv.gov.il/arcgis/rest/services/IView2Ortho2021/MapServer

I can access the tiles using a /{z}/{x}/{y} URL, like this:
https://gisn.tel-aviv.gov.il/arcgis/rest/services/IView2Ortho2021/MapServer/tile/6/47616/41212

I can think of few options to try to achieve this:

- I have no experience with ArcGIS; can I request from MapServer tiles at a different projection/srs?
- Can I specify an SRS or tell Mapbox a transformation to use when fetching tiles?
- Are there any apps/servers that can act as a proxy and will do that transformations for me?

What's the best approach here?

Comment: Answer to all three of your questions is: no. Mapbox has only limited number of supported projections, see https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/projection/